# Vaadin ComboBox Possible to Remove or Disable "Picker" Icon?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Vaadin 7.6.2

How-to disable or deactivate a Vaadin ComboBox picker icon?  I want the field to look like a TextField without the picker arrow on the far right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for hiding button:

```java
ComboBox c1 = new ComboBox();
c1.setStyleName("no-picker");
```

```css
.v-filterselect-no-picker .v-filterselect-button {
    display: none;
}
```

There is no Vaadin core style for this.